# SQL Query to delete a comment and all its children in MySQL and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have a comments table.

- id
- section_id
- parent_comment_id
- root_id
- content

It supports multi-level commenting.

If the comment is at the top most position, it's `root_id` is `NULL` and it's `parent_comment_id` is `NULL`.

If the comment is underneath another comment: the parent_comment_id equals to the comment Id of the comment which is just one level underneath it. The root_id for all child comments will be the Id of the top most comment in which that comment is underneath it.

Example:

```
[id=1] [parent_comment_id=null] [root_id=null]
  [id=2] [parent_comment_id=1] [root_id=1]
  [id=3] [parent_comment_id=1] [root_id=1]
    [id=4] [parent_comment_id=3] [root_id=1]
      [id=5] [parent_comment_id=4] [root_id=1]
    [id=12] [parent_comment_id=3] [root_id=1]
  [id=6] [parent_comment_id=1] [root_id=1]

[id=2] [parent_comment_id=null] [root_id=null]
```

I have no control over the database Schema. So I can't make changes. There is also no foreign key constraint set up in the table for any of these columns.

What I am having problem with is to create a function, probably a **recursive function**, that gets a comment Id and deletes that comment and all its childs, childs in all levels. This can be a comment anywhere in the tree.

Here is something that I am trying now:

```
 protected void DeleteChildComments(comment c)
 {
      // get all comments with c.id as its parent_id
      List<comment> oneLevelDownSubComments = new List<comment>();

      using (phEntities db = new phEntities())
       {
           oneLevelDownSubComments = db.comments.Where(x => x.parent_comment_id == c.id).ToList<comment>();    

       }

        if (oneLevelDownSubComments.Count == 0)
        {
            // no children, just delete the comment
            using (phEntities db = new (phEntities())
            {
                db.comments.Remove(c);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // has children
            foreach(var item in oneLevelDownSubComments)
            {
                DeleteChildComments(item);
            }
        }

    }
```

I am developing in ASP.NET 4.5 C# and Entity Framework against a MySQL 5 Database.

Comment: You should be able to use a cascading foreign key constraint for this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There is no constraint on any of those columns.

Comment: Can you create a database object?  Cold you add a trigger to the table?

Comment: @TroyWitthoeft No, I can't create a trigger. The project uses entity framework, so I have access to the objects that represents the columns of the table so I can query the database like db.comments.where(x => x.id == 1).

Comment: There may be a recursive function, but it could be simpler? It looks like two delete statements in serial would get it done.  DELETE where `root_id=1` (children) and then followed by a DELETE where 'id=1' (parent).

Comment: @TroyWitthoeft If I want to delete just comment id=4 and it's children. Your idea won't work.  There is a complex structure underneath each comment with children that have children as well. Deleting where root_ud=1 will delete the entire comments related to that top comment. I don't want all of them to be deleted. This is why a recursion is necessary.

Comment: Well then, build a recursive function. Sounds nice. Three deletes gets it done.  Starting at most granular, then working up the chain.  Get the Comments ID
`int CommentID = 4`
And issue three delete staments, in this order.
DELETE where `root_id=CommentID` 
DELETE where 'parent_comment_id=CommentID' 
DELETE where `id=CommentID'

Improve on that if you will, but it works for all IDs.

Comment: @TroyWitthoeft Ii've updated the question with something I am trying, care to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I finally made it, here is the code:

```
  protected void DeleteChildComments(comment c, phEntities db) {
   if (c != null) {
    // get all comments with c.id as its parent_id
    List <comment> oneLevelDownSubComments = new List <comment> ();

    oneLevelDownSubComments =
        db.comments.Where(x => x.parent_comment_id == c.id).ToList <comment> ();

    if (oneLevelDownSubComments.Count == 0) {
     // no children, just delete the comment

     db.comments.Remove(c);
     db.SaveChanges();
    } else {
     // has children, delete them
     foreach(var item in oneLevelDownSubComments) {
      DeleteChildComments(item, db);
     }

     // delete itself if has no children
     DeleteChildComments(c, db);
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something similar to this?

```
protected void DeleteComment(comment c)
{
    int id = c.id

    //Three lists to hold the self-referencing objects
    List<comment> rootCommentsToBeDeleted = new List<comment>();
    List<comment> parentCommentsToBeDeleted = new List<comment>();
    List<comment> commentsToBeDeleted = new List<comment>();

    using (phEntities db = new phEntities())
    {

        //Get all comments to lists
        rootCommentsToBeDeleted = db.comments.Where(x => x.root_id == id).ToList<comment>();    
        parentCommentsToBeDeleted = db.comments.Where(x => x.parent_comment_id == id).ToList<comment>();    
        commentsToBeDeleted = db.comments.Where(x => x.id == id).ToList<comment>();    

        //Combine lists
        commentsToBeDeleted.AddRange(rootCommentsToBeDeleted);
        commentsToBeDeleted.AddRange(parentCommentsToBeDeleted);

        //Delete records
        db.comments.RemoveRange(commentsToBeDeleted);
        db.SaveChanges();

    }

}
```

Comment: I has to be recursive because there are infinite levels and I need to traverse through the tree from bottom to the first comment.  I've added my answer which recursively traverse over the tree until it each the comment to be deleted and delete it as well. Thank for your answer though.

Comment: Oh sorry.  I didn't know you were working against an *infinite level* tree.   It only looked like three to me.

Comment: That was an example, but I've shown several depths in the question. Anyways, thanks for trying to help my friend.

Comment: Got it.  Then, yes I think you've found the answer to your problem.  Upvoted your answer.  :)